# The method that the structure implements the interface will be called automatically

Tags: go

I learned golang through The Go Programming Language.

```
package io

// Writer is the interface that wraps the basic Write method.
type Writer interface {
    // Write writes len(p) bytes from p to the underlying data stream.
    // It returns the number of bytes written from p (0 <= n <= len(p))
    // and any error encountered that caused the write to stop early.
    // Write must return a non-nil error if it returns n < len(p).
    // Write must not modify the slice data, even temporarily.
    //
    // Implementations must not retain p.
    Write(p []byte) (n int, err error)
}
```

In Chapter 7, there was an example, which defined a ByteCounter type and implemented the Write method of the io.Writer interface.

```
type ByteCounter int

func (c *ByteCounter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    *c += ByteCounter(len(p)) // convert int to ByteCounter
    return len(p), nil
}
```

Next, ByteCounter is instantiated and the Write method is executed, so the Write method calculates the length of 'hello' and assigns it to the pointer of c, so the value of c becomes 5. Here I understand

```
var c ByteCounter
c.Write([]byte("hello"))
fmt.Println(c) // "5", = len("hello")
```

I couldn't understand right away

```
func Fprintf(w io.Writer, format string, args ...interface{}) (int, error)
```

The Fprintf source code above, in the following example, because &ByteCounter implements the Write method, it can be used as the io.Write interface as the first parameter of Fprintf. Then Fprintf is executed, the value of c becomes 12, which is the length of'hello, Dolly'. This change is because the Write method of ByteCounter is executed. Why is it executed automatically without calling it here? What is the process?

```
c = 0          // reset the counter
var name = "Dolly"
fmt.Fprintf(&c, "hello, %s", name)
fmt.Println(c) // "12", = len("hello, Dolly")
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the source code, you will see this:

```
func Fprintf(w io.Writer, format string, a ...interface{}) (n int, err error) {
   p := newPrinter()
   p.doPrintf(format, a)
   n, err = w.Write(p.buf)
   p.free()
   return
}
```

So when you call `Fprintf`, internally `Write` is called.

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.16.2/src/fmt/print.go#L202-L208